# How to specify JSON parameters in a WADL file?

Tags: json, rest, wadl, sap-data-services

Dear Stack Overflow Experts,

We have a requirement to access an API from SAP BODS. SAP BODS needs a WADL file configured in order to access the API. The API we are trying to call is a rest services API with a POST method and accepts only JSON parameters as input.

I have tried using SOAP UI to generate the WADL file but the WADL file does not include the JSON input parameters in the file.

Can anyone help me with a sample code of how a JSON input can be specified as a parameter in the WADL file.

I have tried going through all the documentation that is available but could not come across anything that could help.

I am new to API and any help is appreciated.